# Basic question about encoding ZFC into PA

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations

**1)** Are ZFC and PA arithmetic mutually interpretable if we extend PA to PA+A , where A is the set formulas of PA that result from the translation of the axioms of ZFC (or any large cardinal axioms extension of it)?

Assuming the answer is yes:

**2)** It is not clear to me if the formulas of ZFC, which in the language  $L_{\in}$ can be be written in $\Pi^0_n$ or $\Sigma^0_n$ format, are also translated into $\Pi^0_n$ or $\Sigma^0_n$ formulas of PA, or if we need to use higher order formulas of PA (I mean, if first-order PA is not enough).

**3)** In such a case, are the higher order formulas ($\Pi^m_n$ or $\Sigma^m_n$, with $m,n \in Z $) of PA enough, or are there still formulas of ZFC (for instance, some large cadinal axioms) that cannot be translated (coded?) into any $\Pi^m_n$ or $\Sigma^m_n$ formula of PA? Well if such were the case then, I guess that ZFC+Large Cardinals and PA+A  would not be mutually interpretable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the answer is no.

When it comes to interpretations, there is actually quite a spectrum of slightly different notions. What seems to be the standard modern reference is:

> Albert Visser. *Categories of theories and interpretations*. In **Logic in Tehran**, 284–341, Lect. Notes Log., **26**, Assoc. Symbol. Logic, La Jolla, CA, 2006. [MR2262326 (2007j:03083)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2262326).

In any case, at the very least you want an interpretation of a theory $T$ in a theory $S$ to satisfy that there is a more or less explicit "procedure" that assigns to each model of $S$ a model of $T$. However this is formalized, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ should be more than enough to carry out this assignment.

It follows that, since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves the consistency of $\mathsf{PA}+A$, then the latter cannot interpret $\mathsf{ZFC}$: Otherwise, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ would prove its own consistency, against the incompleteness theorem. The argument does not change even if you let $A$ consist of all higher order formulas as you suggest in item 3.

On the other hand, (assuming the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}$) if you allow the inclusion in $A$ of arithmetic consequences of large cardinal assumptions, then $\mathsf{ZFC}$ cannot interpret $\mathsf{PA}+A$: Otherwise, from any model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ we would obtain a model of $\mathsf{PA}+\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC+\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})})$. From this, we actually get $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC+\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})})$ in the model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, since this is a $\Pi^0_1$ statement. But this means that the theory $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ proves its own consistency, against the incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andres, I've got it. The only detail that I do not get intuitively is that "ZFC proves the consistency of PA+A". Is there any trivial way to see it or is it just a well known theorem?

Comment: The ordinal $\omega$ with ordinal addition and multiplication models true arithmetic. In particular, it satisfies $\mathsf{PA}$ and any arithmetic consequence of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Note that if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves a sentence, then the arithmetic statement stating this fact is true and therefore holds in $\omega$. If we look at second or third or higher order consequences (in the language of arithmetic) of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then $\omega$ is again a model for these statements, with second order variables interpreted as subsets of $\omega$, third order as subsets of $\mathcal P(\omega)$, etc.

Comment: But this is why I started my answer with "If I understand correctly". Perhaps you mean something else when you talk of a sentence in the language of arithmetic being the translation of an axiom of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. *There is no such translation*, so I am taking $A$ instead to be the set of arithmetic (or higher order) consequences of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. In particular, any true assertion of the form "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves $\phi$" can be written as a (true) arithmetic statement $p_\phi$, which therefore belongs to $A$. (But I wouldn't call $p_\phi$ a "translation" of $\phi$.)

Comment: (On the other hand, if by "the translation of the axiom $\phi$" you mean a Gödel number for $\phi$, then this is literally just a number, not a sentence. Which is why $p_\phi$ as in the previous comment seems like a reasonable alternative.)